# Is there any alternative to captcha?

Tags: php, captcha

I use capcha in user registration form devloped in PHP. But I found that users are struggling to get the words right the first time and they think it is very long and boring process. I want to keep my registration form as simple as possible. hence I want to remove this capcha from my site. But we knows some time its possible that any intruder will try to insert bulk data in user registration step. to restrict it we need the captcha. So the my question is, is there an alternative to captcha?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You could do a '2 + 2 = ' box where the user would need to input the right word to register?

Comment: there are many alternatives like text capcha, dragdrop captcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate the form client side, then validate the data server side if needed and restrict the number of registration attempts.

You can also include a hidden form field, and if it contains a value when checking server side reject the registration as a bot has most likely filled in the form field automatically. A real user wouldn't see it and it won't contain a value

Comment: +1 for the hidden input option.